# ngModelChange not called when changing the model from component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm new in Angular and I'm trying to understand how to connect different controllers in order to change the value of the controllers when one change.

In this particular case I have a form with ngModel and trying to use ngModelChange to update the value of other property in my model, the issue is that ngModelChange is called when the user is interact with the control, but not being called when updating the model from the component.

Let me show you an example code.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-z2q4mr

HTML Template:

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)">
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Field 1</mat-label>
    <input matInput name="field1" [(ngModel)]="MyItem.field1" (ngModelChange)="changeField2($event)">
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Field 2</mat-label>
    <input matInput disabled name="field2" [(ngModel)]="MyItem.field2" (ngModelChange)="changeField3($event)">
  </mat-form-field>
  
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Field 3</mat-label>
    <input matInput disabled name="field3" [(ngModel)]="MyItem.field3">
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Component

```
import { OnInit, Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-component1',
  templateUrl: './component1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component1.component.css']
})
export class Component1Component implements OnInit  {
  MyItem : any = {}

    constructor() {
      }
      
    ngOnInit(): void {
    }
    
    changeField2(event: any){
        this.MyItem.field2 = this.MyItem.field1 + " modification field 2"; //We can see that everytime field1 is changed is updating field2
    }
    
    changeField3(event: any) {
        this.MyItem.field3 = this.MyItem.field2 + " modification field 3"; //Eventhough we are updating field2, this is not being called
    }
}
```

I'm expecting to get field3 automatically updated if I changed field1 (because it is related by field2). Of course I have considered to call `changeField3` on `changeField2`, but if I have a form with a lot of controllers, this is so chaotic the same operation can be called from different methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do what I needed using reactive-forms and the property `ValueChanges` to capture when the value of the controllers change. This executes even if the controller value was changed by a method in the component.

Here you have the same example using reactive-forms:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gh7zho

HTML Template:

```
<form [formGroup]="testForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Field 1</mat-label>
    <input matInput name="field1" formControlName="field1" />
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Field 2</mat-label>
    <input matInput name="field2" formControlName="field2" />
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Field 3</mat-label>
    <input matInput name="field3" formControlName="field3" />
  </mat-form-field>

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<button (click)="resetField2()">Reset field2</button>
```

Component

```
import { OnInit, Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  testForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    field1: [{ value: '', disabled: false }, Validators.required],
    field2: [{ value: '', disabled: true }, Validators.required],
    field3: [{ value: '', disabled: true }, Validators.required]
  });
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    const field1 = this.testForm.get('field1');
    const field2 = this.testForm.get('field2');

    field1!.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
      this.changeField2();
    });

    field2!.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
      this.changeField3();
    });
  }

  changeField2() {
    this.testForm
      .get('field2')!
      .setValue(this.testForm.get('field1')!.value + ' modification field 2'); //We can see that everytime field1 is changed is updating field2
  }

  changeField3() {
    this.testForm
      .get('field3')!
      .setValue(this.testForm.get('field2')!.value + ' modification field 3'); //Eventhough we are updating field2, this is not being called
  }

  resetField2() {
    this.testForm.get('field2')!.setValue(''); //This should leave field2 with only modification field 3
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.warn(this.testForm.value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Field3` doesn't get updated because you don't type anything in to the `Field2`.

> (ngModelChange) is the @Output of ngModel directive. It fires when
> the model changes.

To make your example work you have to mutate third field along with second when the first is changes

```
  changeField2(event: any) {
    this.MyItem.field2 = this.MyItem.field1 + ' modification field 2'; 
    this.MyItem.field3 = this.MyItem.field2 + ' modification field 3';
  }
```

Another way to achieve what you want is to use `ReactiveForms`
[Playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xghfk9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: As I have said in my question I wouldn't like to call changeField3 in changeField2 or update the value in the same method because I have several inputs where all controllers depends on all. In your example you are using `combineLatest` which seems to concat the values when both have values. Is there any other method that I can use to listen changes on controllers?

Comment: I think it's the only solution with `ngModel` since you can only listen to `ngModelChanges` when you actually type in there.

Comment: Also you could check out a nice package for Angular reactive forms https://github.com/ngneat/reactive-forms

Comment: Is there no way to do this without using any other package? For example this can be done with using Reactive Forms?

Answer (score 0):

in this case, you can use `(change)` in your form tag in HTML

```
<form #f="ngForm" (change)="changeField3()">
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Field 1</mat-label>
    <input matInput name="field1" [(ngModel)]="MyItem.field1" (ngModelChange)="changeField2($event)">
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Field 2</mat-label>
    <input matInput disabled name="field2" [(ngModel)]="MyItem.field2" >
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Field 3</mat-label>
    <input matInput disabled name="field3" [(ngModel)]="MyItem.field3">
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

and in Ts

```
  changeField3() {
   
    this.MyItem.field3 = this.MyItem.field2 + ' modification field 3'; 
  }
```

this approach listen to every change in your form model

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, this can be useful for my case, but it is executing only when it lost the focus from the input, is there anyway it executes everytime the input changed (like onKeyPress for example)?

Comment: In your case, we do not have any choice for use  " (change) " but if you use Reactive forms or Formly for this form you can listen to every change